# using agrepl within a loop -- 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, purrr, agrep

I'm trying to go through a list of artists and albums, and get the audio features of each song of each album into a data frame (using spotifyr package). However, in my list, there are some misspellings of the album titles, so I'm trying to use agrep or agrepl to fuzzy match

For example:

```
library(spotifyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

Artist <- c("Eminem", "Spiritualized")
Album <- c("Revival", "Pure Phase")
mydata <- data_frame(Artist, Album)
```

The `get_artist_audio_features()` function from spotifyr gives back the audio features for every song from the artist, but I only want songs from some specific album.

```
get_album_data <- function(x) {
  get_artist_audio_features(mydata$Artist[x]) %>%
    filter(agrepl(album_name, mydata$Album[x]) == TRUE)}

try_get_album_data <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(get_album_data(x), error = function(e) {data.frame()})}

map_df(seq(1,2), try_get_album_data)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

`...argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Any ideas? I know I need to loop through agrepl somehow, but I'm not sure how to implement that within the `filter()` function, or if I even need `filter()`.

Comment: you can transform your vector of name in a regular expression with `paste(album_name,sep="|")` in the grep it will check name1 or name2 or name 3...

Comment: So like this?

   `filter(agrepl(paste(album_name, sep = "|"), mydata$Album[x]) == TRUE)`

Because that still gives me the same warning as before

Comment: i have no warning when i try

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that agrepl takes the pattern first and the vector second, so in this case, it should be:

`filter(agrepl(mydata$Album[x], album_name) == TRUE)}`

rather than

`filter(agrepl(album_name, mydata$Album[x]) == TRUE)}`

Comment: and actually, the `== TRUE` isn't necessary